# How to show pods status in environment?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We use gitlab, and all of our deployments are in Kubernetes. We have a problem that developers can't see the pod status and container logs of their deployments. In the gitlab [blog post about KAS](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2022/06/08/configuring-your-cluster-with-kubernetes-integration/) there is information that by using KAS we can solve such problems. But in the official docs I can't find any info on how to make it possible. How to configure such integration between kube cluster and giltab if it is possible?

I configured KAS agent, linked it with gitlab project and made simple deployment (nginx with 3 replicas) with gitlab environment via CI/CD workflow. I expected that on environment page I would see how many pods in deployment but there is no such information.

Answer (score 0):

After some research and testing, I found out that there is no such functionality. The information displayed in GitLab/KAS integration is very poor and not functional.

KAS is positioned more as a tool for CI/CD or GitOps, not for monitoring or observability.